# ¿Conjugastes los verbos así?

Tags: conjugación, estados-unidos

He observado en Estados Unidos que algunos latinos agregan una *s* a los verbos indicativos del pretérito en segunda persona: *¿Cúanto pagastes? ¿A dónde fuistes?*

¿Qué ajuste lingüístico provoca tal forma? ¿Dónde se ha normalizado?

Comment: Son jergas populares que detonan un mal vocabulario. No está normalizado y no deberían ser usadas de esa forma las palabras, no obstante, hay personas que crecieron en lugares donde se considera normal (mas no correcto) el uso de las palabras agregando una `s`.

Comment: Te dejo un artículo mío donde hablo de esto: https://www.delcastellano.com/error-preterito-perfecto-simple/ Se da también mucho en partes de España como Madrid.

Comment: No se de donde surgieron estos regionalismos pero sin duda son encontrados en las zonas con menos desarrollo academico que en otras, que podria bien ser considerada una deformacion vulgar del languaje

Comment: Es un vulgarismo común, evitar su uso